# Ring buffer: Disadvantages by moving through memory backwards?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, embedded, avr, circular-buffer

This is probably language agnostic, but I'm asking from a C++ background.

I am hacking together a ring buffer for an embedded system (AVR, 8-bit). Let's assume:

```
const uint8_t size = /* something > 0 */;
uint8_t buffer[size];
uint8_t write_pointer;
```

There's this neat trick of `&`ing the write and read pointers with `size-1` to do an efficient, branchless rollover if the buffer's `size` is a power of two, like so:

```
// value = buffer[write_pointer];
write_pointer = (write_pointer+1) & (size-1);
```

If, however, the size is not a power of two, the fallback would probably be a compare of the pointer (i.e. index) to the size and do a conditional reset:

```
// value = buffer[write_pointer];
if (++write_pointer == size) write_pointer ^= write_pointer;
```

Since the reset occurs rather rarely, this should be easy for any branch prediction.

This assumes though that the pointers need to be advancing foreward in memory. While this is intuitive, it requires a load of `size` in every iteration. I assume that reversing the order (advancing *backwards*) would yield better CPU instructions (i.e. `jump if not zero`) in the regular case, since `size` is only required during the reset.

```
// value = buffer[--write_pointer];
if (write_pointer == 0) write_pointer = size;
```

so

**TL;DR: My question is:** Does marching backwards through memory have a negative effect on the execution time due to cache misses (since memory cannot simply be read forward) or is this a valid optimization?

Comment: For a reasonable answer, I think you're going to have to specify a hardware platform...

Comment: It's 8-bit AVR, added that. I'm also interested in "larger" systems though, since the fundamental principle should be the same.

Comment: One potential win would be if you can avoid having to do a (fetch base, fetch offset, add them) operation for each memory access, unless you can use an addressing mode which does that for free, without extra cycles.  But it's also worth considering how tight this loop is - if access is only infrequent it may not be possible to keep the values in registers.  For your target in question, examining the assembly output is probably going to be the most informative.

Comment: At the assembly level, there's also another potential (if rather naughty) possibility: have the base be the end of the buffer such that zero is the last index (or even one after the last), reset the index to negative values, then increment it.

Comment: Does the AVR8 even have a data cache? We're talking about a primitive 8-bit MCU here...

Comment: There is no reason to do this *wrapping*.  Just increment until the unsigned integer rolls over.  Change your indexing to be `buffer[write_idx & SIZE-1];` and `buffer[read_idx & SIZE-1];`  You can see this in [**kfifo.h**](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/kfifo.h).  Only the accessing needs a mask.  All other operations can use the un-altered integer.  Note, that the *atomic* nature of these routines depend on atomic *integer* writes and reads.  You may not have this on an *eight bit* CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an 8 bit avr with a cache?  And branch prediction?

How does forward or backwards matter as far as caches are concerned?  The hit or miss on a cache is anywhere within the cache line, beginning, middle, end, random, sequential, doesnt matter.  You can work from the back to the front or the front to back of a cache line, it is the same cost (assuming all other things held constant) the first mist causes a fill, then that line is in cache and you can access any of the items in any pattern at a lower latency until evicted.

On a microcontroller like that you want to make the effort, even at the cost of throwing away some memory, to align a circular buffer such that you can mask.  There is no cache the instruction fetches are painful because they are likely from a flash that may be slower than the processor clock rate, so you do want to reduce instructions executed, or make the execution a little more deterministic (same number of instructions every loop until that task is done).  There might be a pipeline that would appreciate the masking rather than an if-then-else.

> TL;DR: My question is: Does marching backwards through memory have a
>   negative effect on the execution time due to cache misses (since
>   memory cannot simply be read forward) or is this a valid optimization?

The cache doesnt care, a miss from any item in the line causes a fill, once in the cache any pattern of access, random, sequential forward or back, or just pounding on the same address, takes less time being in faster memory.  Until evicted.  Evictions wont come from neighboring cache lines they will come from cache lines larger powers of two away, so whether the next cache line you pull is at a higher address or lower, the cost is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Does marching backwards through memory have a negative effect on the
>   execution time due to cache misses (since memory cannot simply be read
>   forward)

Why do you think that you will have a cache miss? You will have a cache miss if you try to access outside the cache (forward or backward).

Comment: I would also have a cache miss if the data requested is not in the cache. From my understanding, the surrounding memory is fetched and cached; I assume that this would be the memory after the accessed location or beginning at the preceding memory boundary. Part of the question is in how far this assumption is true.

Comment: Speaking as someone who sometimes thinks in terms of gates, I think it's more likely that caching would be done in *aligned* chunks including the requested address rather than forward for some fixed size from the requested address - but I can't promise the decision looked the same to whoever actually designed your hardware.  It might be interesting to see if you could measure an effect by benchmarking a test where you move the base address of the buffer within a larger allocation after each trial, recording its absolute start to graph against.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of points which need clarification:

1. That size needs to be loaded each and every time (it's const, therefore ought to be immutable)
2. That your code is correct. For example in a 0-based index (as used in C/C++ for array  access) the value `0' is a valid pointer into the buffer, and the value`size' is not. Similarly there is no need to `xor` when you could simply assign `0`, equally a modulo operator will work (`writer_pointer = (write_pointer +1) % size`).
3. What happens in the general case with virtual memory (i.e. the logically adjacent addresses might be all over the place in the real memory map), paging (stuff may well be cached on a page-by-page basis) and other factors (pressure from external processes, interrupts)

In short: this is the kind of optimisation that leads to more feet related injuries than genuine performance improvements. Additionally it is almost certainly the case that you get much, much better gains using vectorised code (SIMD).

EDIT: And in interpreted languages or JIT'ed languages it might be a tad optimistic to assume you can rely on the *use* of `JNZ` and others at all. At which point the question is, how much of a difference is there really between `loading size` and comparing versus comparing with `0`.

Comment: Speaking of embedded systems, modulo is an extremely slow operation on some architectures, hence my goal to avoid it. In the third example, `value` is indeed outside of the index, which is why I decrease the pointer before accessing the array.
The value `0` doesn't need to be loaded, since `jnz` is an instruction on probably every architecture out there.

Comment: Edited to clarify. Basically the "language-agnostic" tag implies that the use of JNZ is a dubious assumption.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, when performing any form of manual code optimization, *you must have extensive in-depth knowledge of the specific hardware*. If you don't have that, then you should not attempt manual optimizations, end of story.

Thus, your question is filled with various strange assumptions:

- First, you assume that `write_pointer = (write_pointer+1) & (size-1)` is more efficient than something else, such as the XOR example you posted. You are just guessing here, you will have to disassemble the code and see which yields the less CPU instructions.

  Because, when writing code for a tiny, primitive 8-bit MCU, there is not much going on in the core to speed up your code. I don't know AVR8, but it seems likely that you have a small instruction pipe and that's it. It seems quite unlikely that you have much in the way of branch prediction. It seems *very* unlikely that you have a data and/or instruction cache. Read the friendly CPU core manual.
- As for marching backwards through memory, it will unlikely have any impact at all on your program's performance. On old, crappy compilers you would get slightly more efficient code if the loop condition was a comparison vs zero instead of a value. On modern compilers, this shouldn't be an issue. As for cache memory concerns, I doubt you have any cache memory to worry about.

The best way to write efficient code on 8-bit MCUs is to stick to 8-bit arithmetic whenever possible and to avoid 32-bit arithmetic like the plague. And forget you ever heard about something called floating point. *This* is what will make your program efficient, you are unlikely to find any better way to manually optimize your code.